# How do I update my other views when a coreData value changes?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

As of now in my profile view, when a user updates their macroGoals I want the other views to be able to load them instantly and render them into a view. Is there any sort of way of setting an environment object equal to some coreData entity values everytime a user opens the application?

So my environment object:

```
import Foundation

class UserInfoModel: ObservableObject {

    static let shared: UserInfoModel = UserInfoModel() // <<: Here

   
    struct DailyCalorieGoals: Identifiable{
        var id = UUID()
        var calorieGoal: Double
        var fatGoal: Double
        var proteinGoal: Double
        var carbGoal: Double

    }
    @Published var personDailyCalorieGoals = DailyCalorieGoals.init(calorieGoal: 2400, fatGoal: 40, proteinGoal: 40, carbGoal: 40)

}
```

So I have two views, as tab views. When i input some data, I have some coreData values that get saved when the users leaves the application. How do I set these environment objects equal to that data when the application opens?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [NotificationCenter](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-post-messages-using-notificationcenter) to have an `@objc` method run in each of the viewControllers, and post a notification whenever you're modifying the value of your CoreData model.

To answer your question regarding how to initialize a view with the latest data, look no further than `viewDidLoad()`, which is run every time that the app opens again.Fetch the objects from coredata, and use their values to set the value of your enviornment objects.